# Get specific characters within characters' boundaries in a string c#

Tags: c#, string, char

A newbie in this regard here.

While a code line like the following could return entire set of digits (0 to 9) from a string:

```
return new string(Entry2BConsidered.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

Is there a similar way to return only characters within boundaries / limits, something like (0 to 5) or (A to E) or (a to e)?

For example in an input like "AbcdE" how to return b to d.

Something like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char StartChar = 'b'; char EndChar = 'd';
        String MainString = "AbdcdEAabxdcLdE";
        Console.WriteLine("bdcdabdcd"); //Only characters from b to d required
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results. Do you want the returned string to contain duplicate characters?

Comment: For example, consider an input of "AbcdE" to return only "bcd" if char is between 'b' to 'd'

Comment: A `char` is just a glorified number. You could just do `.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '5')`

Comment: Your example is flawed or your wording is flawed, if a character is truly between b and d it would only produce c

Comment: Yep! Wording was flawed. I meant b to d, i.e. both inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is a regex. But then i depends what you realy want in detail. Do you want everything between the first `b` and the last `d` than thats easy

```
var input = "AbdcdEAabxdcLdE";
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "b.*d");

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine($"Success: {match.Value}");
```

for case insensitive search you have two options search for `b` or `B` as start character and `d` or `D` as end character

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "[bB].*[dD]");
```

or better make the seach case insensitive by passing an option:

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "b.*d", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you want part of the string but only the part the contains letters `b` to `d` you could do this:

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "[b-d]+", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Edit: add version to filter all except the given characters

If you want all characters that are between `b` and `d` and filter oute everything else you would write:

```
var input = "AbdcdEAabxdcLdE";
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, "[b-d]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var result = string.Join("", matches.Select(m => m.Value));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes! However, it's bdcdabdcd that is required via Regex type technique instead of looping each character throughout the string.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want something like a filter? so that only the characters remain from your filter?

Comment: Thanks again Johannes!

Your edited version does reflect the requisite outcome in the end.